# Unable to load DLL on specific systems only

Tags: c#, windows, dll

We have to deal with a problem on several computers, mainly with Windows 7 pro, but lately occurs with Windows 10 home too.
Our software try to access video file to work with, file located on the computer, and throw an error :

> Unable to load DLL 'EvrPresenter32.dll': The specified module could
>   not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) 
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'EvrPresenter32.dll':
>   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

This seems to occur when calling the function : Presentation.Windows.Controls.DirectShow.EvrPresenter.DllGetClassObject32(Guid, Guid, Object&)

However, EvrPresenter32.dll is present in the software directory where it is supposed to be, alike to computers where all works fine.
This happens with any video format (.wmv, .mp4, .avi...) or video access path.

We've try to manually register the .dll in C:\Windows\sysWOW64\ with regsrv32.exe, but this give an error :

> The module EvrPresenter32.dll failed to load. Make sure the binary is
>   stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with
>   the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module could not be
>   found.

Drivers are up to date.
System is up to date.

Could you please, give us some tips to investigate and solve this problem ?

Comment: *"or dependent .DLL files"* - you might want to look at [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if there are any libraries that `EvrPresenter32.dll` links to but which aren't present.

Comment: This is a wrapper for DirectShow, written in C++/CLI.  It has a dependency on vcruntime140.dll, easy to overlook.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: @WaiHaLee : We've already check this, and it's a good point to investigate. Sadly, Dependency Walker show about 500 missing DDL on each system, working or not. Differences between missing DLL list helped to find that msvcr120.dll may be in cause. An essential clue in problem resolution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant Nov 9 at 10:47

> This is a wrapper for DirectShow, written in C++/CLI. It has a
>   dependency on vcruntime140.dll, easy to overlook.

Next to Wai Ha Lee comment that helped us incriminate msvcr120.dll, we found this DLL is part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package.
After installing it on the system, our software video usage works properly !

Remind to the link to download it from Microsoft :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Added to prerequisites for our software...

Thanks a lot for your concern and help !

Answer (score 0):

When ever we are moving the DLL's from one system to another system DLL will get blocked. So you are getting this issue.

**How to Unblock DLL:**

1. Right click on the DLL
2. Properties >> General
3. At the bottom you will see unblock click on it.

[image]

See the [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file) for details explanation

Comment: Thanks for your concern.
The security part that you describe does not appear on our system. Maybe as the DLL is not just moved from a system to another, but deployed with software installation, so is not blocked.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't figure this error out either it worked fine on Windows 7, but on Windows 10 it doesn't work. I fixed the problem though it had nothing to do with missing dependencies or Runtime redistributable packs.

The problem was I had to pack the DLL with upx and it started working again.

Something with the file being unpacked and compiled on old Windows XP operating system created a bad PE Header or Bad file format or something, but packing it with UPX did the trick works fine now and the DLL got 3x smaller haha.